# Посмотрите пожалуйста. На мобильной версии проблемы с открыванием меню на сайте

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть сайт:
https://evroflag.by/

На мобильной версии проблемы с открыванием меню на сайте.
Меню открывается только **после появления** виджета с мессенджерами.
До этого оно неактивно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это не связано с виджетом, у тебя скрипты отвечающие за меню на lazyload и надо сделать хоть какое-то действие, чтобы они подгрузились.
Решение - убрать их с lazyload
Плюс у тебя файл с этим кодом подгружается раньше JQuery и в консоли появляется ошибка (тут либо подключение JQuery поставить раньше, либо сделать подключение через funtions.php с указанием, что этому файлу нужен JQuery https://denis-creative.com/ispolzovanie-vmesto-jquery-v-shablonah-wordpress/)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                $("#vc_images-carousel-1-1706706627 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                    items: 8, 
                    responsive: {
                        1025: {
                            items: 8
                        },
                        769: {
                            items: 4
                        },
                        577: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        0: {
                            items: 2
                        }
                    },
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    dots: true,
                    nav: true,
                    slideBy:  "page",
                    navText:false,
                    loop: false,
                    onRefreshed: function() {
                        $(window).resize();
                    }
                });
                $(window).resize();
            });
        

            jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                $("#vc_images-carousel-2-1706706627 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                    items: 8, 
                    responsive: {
                        1025: {
                            items: 8
                        },
                        769: {
                            items: 4
                        },
                        577: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        0: {
                            items: 2
                        }
                    },
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    dots: false,
                    nav: false,
                    slideBy:  "page",
                    navText:false,
                    loop: false,
                    onRefreshed: function() {
                        $(window).resize();
                    }
                });
                $(window).resize();
            });
        

            jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                $("#vc_images-carousel-3-1706706628 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                    items: 7, 
                    responsive: {
                        1025: {
                            items: 7
                        },
                        769: {
                            items: 4
                        },
                        577: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        0: {
                            items: 2
                        }
                    },
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    dots: true,
                    nav: true,
                    slideBy:  "page",
                    navText:false,
                    loop: false,
                    onRefreshed: function() {
                        $(window).resize();
                    }
                });
                $(window).resize();
            });
        

            jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
                $("#vc_images-carousel-4-1706706628 .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                    rtl: $("body").hasClass("rtl"),
                    items: 7, 
                    responsive: {
                        1025: {
                            items: 7
                        },
                        769: {
                            items: 4
                        },
                        577: {
                            items: 3
                        },
                        0: {
                            items: 2
                        }
                    },
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
                    dots: true,
                    nav: false,
                    slideBy:  "page",
                    navText:false,
                    loop: false,
                    onRefreshed: function() {
                        $(window).resize();
                    }
                });
                $(window).resize();
            });
```

В принципе `jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {` указывается только 1 раз за файл и код пишется внутри `jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) { "code" });`, а не дублируется перед каждым блоком

Comment: какие именно скрипты нужно убрать из lazyload?

Comment: которые отвечают за кнопку, там много подключений, искать конкретный не буду